# use android application using WAP client

Tags: android

Hello
When i am using my application using WIFI or INTERNET APn it works fine.But provides socket connection error while trying with WAP APN.

Is there anything that i can do to resolve this in android.

Do i need to use any permissions to use my application for WAP?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think it is a permissions issue.

With a WAP data plan you can only connect to standard HTTP ports (ie. 80) and exchange WAP based packets. If your app tries to connect to a different port or exchange non WAP packets, then you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks Federico for your valuable info.Was trying for it since many days.